# RandomShuffleQueue '_1_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 2, current size 0)

Tags: python, tensorflow

> File
>   "C:\Users\Bernhard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-
>   packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2630, in create_op
>   original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def) File
>   "C:\Users\Bernhard\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-
>   packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1204, in **init**
>   self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint:
>   disable=protected- access OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback):
>   RandomShuffleQueue  '_1_shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue' is closed
>   and has insufficient  elements (requested 2, current size 0) [[Node:
>   shuffle_batch = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_UINT8, 
>   DT_UINT8], timeout_ms=-1,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"] (shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue, shuffle_batch/n)]]

Code:

```
def read_and_decode(filename_queue, image_height=384, image_width=384, batch_size=2):
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_data = reader.read(filename_queue)

    features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_data, features={
        'height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'image_raw_t': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'image_raw_t+1': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
    })
    img_t = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw_t'], tf.uint8)
    img_t_ = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw_t+1'], tf.uint8)
    height = tf.cast(features['height'], tf.int32)
    width = tf.cast(features['width'], tf.int32)

    image_shape = tf.stack([height, width, 3])

    img_t = tf.reshape(img_t, image_shape)
    img_t_ = tf.reshape(img_t_, image_shape)

    resized_img_t = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(image=img_t,

    target_height=image_height,

    target_width=image_width)
    resized_img_t_ = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(image=img_t_,

    target_height=image_height,

    target_width=image_width)

    _img_t, _img_t_ = tf.train.shuffle_batch([resized_img_t, resized_img_t_],
                                             batch_size=batch_size,
                                             capacity=10000, num_threads=2,
                                             min_after_dequeue=10)
    return _img_t, _img_t_



write_to_records(feature_list, tfrecords_filename=tfrecords_filename)

filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(string_tensor=
[tfrecords_filename], num_epochs=1)
img_t, img_t_ = read_and_decode(filename_queue)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    for i in range(3):
        im1, im2 = sess.run([img_t, img_t_])

        print(im1[0, :, :, :].shape)
        print('Current Batch')

        plt.imshow(im1[0, :, :, :])
        plt.show()

        plt.imshow(im2[0, :, :, :])
        plt.show()

        plt.imshow(im1[1, :, :, :])
        plt.show()

        plt.imshow(im2[1, :, :, :])
        plt.show()

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Hi guys, I am trying to generate batches from a tfrecords file but am keep getting this error when running my session. I used the Kitti tracking dataset for my tfrecords file.
Any suggestions on what the problem might be?
I thought that maybe the data from the tfrecords file is not correctly read, but so far i found no solution. 
I am using tensorflow-gpu on windows with python 3.5